# Absence of $x,y,z \in \mathbb{Z}_+$ s.t $\forall n>3$ holds $x^n+y^n=z^n$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, contest-math

I saw the following question online(it is question $2$ [here](http://www.stats.uwaterloo.ca/~cgsmall/put1999.2.html)):

> 2. Prove that there do not exist positive integers $x,y,z$ such that $x^n+y^n=z^n$ for $n>3$, $\forall n \in \mathbb{Z}$. Please, don't use Fermat's Last Theorem or any standard weakening of it.

Note that it's not the Fermat's last theorem because it's an infinite set of equations parametrized with $n$.

Comment: Do they mean one triple $(x,y,z)$ for which that equation is meant to hold for all $n≥3$?

Comment: Well, but in that case just remark that $z>\max (x,y)$ so $\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac {z^n}{x^n+y^n}=\infty$.

Comment: Title of this question attracted me.

Comment: Got to hate that someone write quantifiers like this. Quantifiers do not commute. Does it mean "for all integers $n\ge 3$, there do not exist..." or "there do not exist... such that for all integers $n\ge 3$..."?

Comment: @edm: The statement is very clear in my opinion. It's probably meant to trick you into believeing that it's about Fermat's theorem, when in reality it isn't (and it's also quite trivial).

Comment: @edm I agree with Alex...and that's precisely the gist of the question, imo.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Let's suppose there exist such a triple $x,y,z$ such that $x^n+ y^n = z^n$ for all integers $n>2$. Then we have  $$x^3+y^3=z^3$$
Square both sides:
$$ x^6 + 2x^3y^3 + y^6 = z^6$$
Now clearly $2x^3y^3 > 0$ ( $x,y$ are positive integers ) so $$ x^6 + y^6 \neq z^6$$ 
A contradiction.

Comment: As simple and nice as that. +1

Comment: So simple! Fermat Spotted :P